# Equivalent condition for the existence of an injective Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that both $V$ and $W$ are *finite-dimensional*. There exists a *injective* linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $\dim V\leq \dim W$

**Proof.** $(\Rightarrow).$ Assume for the purpose of contradiction that $T:V\to W$ is an *injective linear map* and that $\dim V>\dim W$ thus by making use of the *Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps* we see that 
$$\dim \operatorname{null}\ T = \dim V-\dim \operatorname{range}\ T$$
$$\dim \operatorname{null}\ T \ge \dim V-\dim W$$
$$\dim \operatorname{null}\ T > 0$$
but $T$ is *injective* and thus $\operatorname{null}T = \{0\}$ implying that $\dim \operatorname{null}\ T=0$ resulting in a contradiction.

$(\Leftarrow).$ Assume now that $\dim V\leq\dim W$ since both $V$ and $W$ are *finite dimensional* we may invoke the existence of the vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_m\in V$ and $w_1,w_2,...,w_n\in W$ such that they act as basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively, where $m\leq n$.

Consider now the linear map $T\colon V\to W$ defined as follows.
$$\forall j\in\{1,2,...,m\}(Tv_j = w_j)$$
Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be arbitrary members of $V$ and assume that $Tu_1=Tu_2$, in light of $(1)$ we may express $Tu_1$ and $Tu_2$ as follows
$$Tv_1 = T\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jv_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jTv_j=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jw_j\tag{2}$$
$$Tv_2 = T\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_jv_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_jTv_j=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_jw_j\tag{3}$$
subtracting $(2)$ from $(3)$ we see that
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(b_j-a_j)w_j\tag{4}$$
we know that $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ is a linearly independent list in $W$ consequently $w_1,w_2,...,w_m$ is also linearly independent, it then follows that 
$$\forall j\in\{1,2,...,m\}(a_j=b_j)\tag{5}$$
consequently $u_1=u_2$ as every vector in $V$ is uniquely expressed as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. A few remarks:

- The expression “Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps” is not a standard one. The usual expression is “rank–nullity theorem”.
- In order to prove that the map $T$ that you defined is indeed injective, it is easier to observe that$$\begin{align*}T\left(\sum_{j=1}^ma_jv_j\right)=0&\iff \sum_{j=1}^ma_jw_j=0\\&\iff\bigl(\forall j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\bigr):a_j=0,\end{align*}$$since $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\}$ is a subset of a basis.