# Show that it is impossible for a linear map $F : \mathbb R^3 → \mathbb R^2$ to be one-to-one.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This was a question in a linear algebra text that I'm following.

Although I'm able to figure it out using pigeonhole principle, I'm not sure how I can formally prove this.

Basically I can say that there would be more vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ than $ \mathbb R^2$, thus using pigeonhole it can't be one-to-one, but how do I prove it formally?

Comment: rank-nullity. “more vectors in R3 than R2” is definitely false. The two sets have same cardinality (i.e there exists a bijection… you need to use linearity here to show the non-existence).

Comment: @peek-a-boo what's rank nullity, I haven't come across that term yet.

Comment: I mean let me check "rank-nullity" out on my own

Comment: google it. Or just try to write out a system of equations. THis is a small enough case that you can do things explicitly.

Comment: also why is "more vectors in R3 than R2" is definitely false. I mean if in R2, let S represent complete set of vectors with rational entries, then in R3, I can alway have S*infinite number of vectors.

Comment: again, google it. I’ve already told you the reason: there exists a bijection (as has been discussed several times on this site).

Comment: @aroma: Cardinality doesn't work like that for infinite sets.  The standard example: on the one hand there are "obviously twice as many" integers as there are even integers, yet on the other hand they are the same number because the map $n \mapsto 2n$ is 1-1 and onto.  So being able to identify each element of a set $A$ with lots of elements of a set $B$, is not a proof that there cannot be a bijection between them.

Comment: The big punchline here is that you are asked about showing that no **linear** maps from $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2$ exist which are one-to-one.  Any attempt at a proof which does not take advantage of the fact that the maps you are considering are *linear* must be false (*Again, because as alluded to before, there exist nonlinear bijections between $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent condition for the existence of an injective Linear Map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399487/equivalent-condition-for-the-existence-of-an-injective-linear-map) Actually you don't really need the rank nullity theorem. Simply use that an injective linear map preserves linear independence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: suppose $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear and 1-1.  Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Prove that $T e_1, T e_2, T e_3$ are not only distinct, but are actually *linearly independent*.  Then recall, or prove, that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension 2 and cannot have a linearly independent set of more than 2 vectors.

This is the type of "pigeonhole" argument you usually want.  Not that $\mathbb{R}^3$ has more vectors *total* than $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is in fact false), but that a *basis* for $\mathbb{R}^3$ has more vectors than a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong:
lets say e1,e2,e3 map to Te1,Te2,Te3, now we need to prove that there exists atleast two set of vectors which maps to one output vector in R2. 

Now we know that O(null vector) maps to O. 
and T(ae1 + be2 + ce3) also maps to zero vector as there can't be more than 2 linearly independent vectors in R2.

hence we've proved.

Am I right here?

Comment: @aroma: You have skipped several steps.  You should prove more carefully that there must exist $a,b,c$, not all zero, such that $T(a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3) = 0$.

Comment: I can do that like this : 
Te1, Te2, Te3 can't be linearly independent thus we will have a set of rational numbers(where atleast one is non zero) such that a(Te1) + b(Te2) + c(Te3) = 0,
now since T is linear and TP+TQ = T(P + Q) for some vectors P & Q, I can say that there exists a set of a,b,c such that  a(Te1) + b(Te2) + c(Te3) = T(ae1 + be2 + ce3) = 0;

is it correct to say this is a complete proof now?

Comment: @aroma: There is no reason to assume that $a,b,c$ would be *rational* numbers, they could very well be irrational.  But that doesn't matter, just say "real numbers".  Otherwise it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

We know $\mathbb{R}^2$ is canonical considered as a vectorial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If $F$ : $ \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear and injective then the restriction $F_{|\mathbb R^2}$ is a bijection of a (strict) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then all image by $F$ of any element of
the complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ should be necessarily equal to another $F(v)$ where $v$ is an element of the above mentioned subspace. Thus $F$ would not be 1-to-1.

Comment: I can't see why you say the restriction is onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. That's as deep a result as what we are trying to prove.

Comment: It is quite known and  elementary that injective, onto and biyective are equivalent for a linear function of $V$ in $V$ where $V$ is a vectorial space of finite dimension.

Comment: Yes, but knowing that is essentially knowing rank-nullity which trivially answers the OP's question: and OP says that they don't know rank-nullity.